# Google Chrome printing images in low resolution

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have a page with some images. They are resized with CSS. Here is how:

```
@media print {

.img-thumbnail {
  width: 45vw;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

It looks perfect on the screen, but when I actually print or export them to PDF from Chrome, the result is this:

[image: A low resolution piece of crap]

Whereas if I print it from Firefox...

[image]

Clearly something is wrong in how Chrome exports images to the print spool. It looks fine in the print preview window, but it gets downscaled. Has anyone met this problem yet?

Comment: We are being bit by this bug also.  It particularly comes up when trying to print from Google Maps (the gf wants paper).  In Firefox everything looks ok, but from Chrome the street names are illegible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just run into this issue myself with printing barcodes for a client's packing slip. I'm not certain if you have resolved this yet, but I wanted to put this here for others that find this page.

It turns out that the CSS tag `filter: grayscale(100%);` causes Chrome to render out the images in a low resolution as you demonstrated above. It turns out that this CSS filter was causing the logo, product images, and barcode on my client's packing slip to be rendered out as demonstrated above.

As soon as I removed the filter tag from the packing slip, the barcode was rendering out at full resolution and able to be scanned by my client's barcode scanner again.

To summarize, removing the CSS tag `filter: grayscale(100%);` resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Mother of all moons! Thanks.